# Installing new gems

Tags: ruby, windows

Hi I am looking to install the win32-service gem in Ruby for Windows, I have tried using the "gem install" command but it doesn't seem to know where to find my gem ;(

I downloaded the gem itself which came with a load of folders but no install instructions.

Is there anyway I can manually install the gem or point IRB in the right direction?

Comment: I just installed it over here on windows 7 and ruby 1.9.3p194. Through gem install win32-service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this command to install gem file manually.

> gem install [your gem file]

Comment: Doesn't work for me I get the following: NameError: undefined local variable or method `win32' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

Comment: @Ninja2k that is because you're using `Interactive Ruby` and not a command prompt. `gem install` commands needs a terminal/command prompt, not inside Ruby itself.

Comment: Thanks Luis that worked perfectly for me, I am just beginning Ruby and I love it.